# Images are not uploading in forms created by adobe livecycle design that are opened in adobe reader 11.0.02

Tags: image, adobe, adobe-reader, livecycle-designer

Forms created in `adobe livecycle designer` are not supported in adobe reader 11.0.02 and 10.1.4

The form has an image field that allows users to upload images and save them in the form. The images are not saving in adobe 11 and adobe 10.

I have tried saving the form in `adobe reader 9.5.0` and there is no issues with the images.

I have also tried setting the form to be compatible with versions 10 and above in the form properties in `adobe livecycle designer`. However, this did not solve the problem.

I would appreciate some assistance with this issue if anyone has experienced the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything on Adobe's known issues for either reader or Livecycle regarding this but if you can share the file I'd be happy to have a look and see if there's anything I can do.

I have had issues in the past with images not displaying and it's worth checking the binding properties are set to Normal rather than None in the object properties because this was previously an issue I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me I had named all of the field names imagefield1. After changing them to a unique name like imagefield1 and imagefield2 the image would save. I think that this is due to the data being binded to the imagefield name.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Image Field in Adobe Live Cycle: The image is linked by default. You need to embed the image if you want it to save with the form. Simply check the box next to Embed Image.